# Debugging Rails 3, how do I make Debugger start with the post-mortem option on?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging

If you pass the `--debugger` option to `rails server` it will load Rack's Debugger (I believe). However, it doesn't start it with the post-mortem option turned out. How and from where do I stop that debugger and start one with post-mortem debugging enabled?